# How to make a working popup box in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I couldn't find any working answers for this, so I finally am asking it here.
I have been working on a Calculator for a while in Visual Studio 2013. In that Calculator program,
I have a Quit button. I want it to be so when a user clicks on "Quit" it has a popup that asks if they are sure, and then I want "OK" to close the program and "Cancel" to bring them back. I have the following code-

```
Private Sub Button18_Click(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to Quit?", 1 + 16, "Quit")
End Sub
```

I have no clue how to make this work, so please answer, if you can help!

Comment: Look into the [FormClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: See [MessageBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx).  It returns a value.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a FormClosing handler, to account for different ways your form can be closed:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object,
                                e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
  If e.CloseReason <> CloseReason.UserClosing Then Return

  Dim res As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
    "Are you sure?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

  Select Case res
    Case DialogResult.OK
      'do nothing, we are already closing
    Case DialogResult.Cancel
      e.Cancel = True
    Case Else
      'should never get here
      Throw New NotImplementedException
  End Select
End Sub
```

Notice a condition on *CloseReason*, this is to prevent an annoying popup when the form is being closed externally, i.e. by a task manager. We only want the popup when it's user closing the form.

Next you need to save a *DialogResult*, returned by `MessageBox.Show`.

Since we are inside the FormClosing event handler, no action means a form will be closed. If you want to *Cancel* form closing, you need to set `e.Cancel = True`. [See FormClosingEventArgs class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

*Case Else* is there if you ever decide to change which buttons are available on the popup, and forget to update your `Select Case` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code answers your question, but follow [Neolisk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938746/1036274) to make a more robust app.

```
Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    Dim result As MsgBoxResult
    result = MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to Quit?", 1 + 16, "Quit")
    If (result = MsgBoxResult.Ok) Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```